# Deleted Google Talk on accident

Tags: google-play-store, apk, uninstallation

Okay, got a bit carried away in Root Explorer and deleted GTalk. Cant access Google Play. I tried reinstalling versions online, those crashed instantly. Then, i grabbed my ROM zip and pulled out Talk.apk and put it into system/App and installed it. Google Talk doesnt crashes anymore, but play still does. Any ideas? I am using a Virgin Mobile WFS.

Sorry for the lack of ' characters, my autocorrect on my phone is being weird.

Comment: Have you tried clearing Google Play cache and data?

Answer (score 1):

I was just browsing around for this issue and found this,

> ```
>     I had exacly the same trouble with Google Play and I have managed to revert it 
>     back to original working version of Android Market. In Options (Android system   
>     settings) go for Applications. Choose Google Play. Clean cached data. Remove this 
>     application. After these steps Google Play dissappeared from my droid and I could   
>     put back Android Market icon onto my desktop and I can use it for installing new 
>     programs.
> ```

Link to source : [Link to forum](http://www.acertabletforum.com/forum/acer-iconia-a501-help/3877-google-play-wont-run-com-android-vending-stopped-working.html)